# LP with expensive lookup of parameters

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I work on the following problem. Given a set of people, a (limited) set of apples, and a corresponding level of satisfaction if a person *i* would eat *j* apples, my goal is to maximize the overall satisfaction of all people. Using LP, this can be expressed as:

[image]

This model works all fine, but I struggle to address one additional constraint. Lookup of *Sat* matrix is expensive, so I cannot retrieve all values to Sat, which is happening now (I use Gurobi). Would you know how to deal with such problem?

Btw. Levels of satisfactions are non-decreasing.

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Be more precise about the exact problem here. (It sounds that you are looking for something like interactive-learning where your solver optimizes which SAT-values to index first and in which order because lookup is costly. But that's A: hard B: not really compatible with LP-solvers).

Comment: I think that your interpretation is correct. The idea is to give a certain amount of apples to each person in a way the overall satisfaction is maximized. That should happen with the minimum number of lookups to _SAT_ matrix. If this is not compatible with LP-solvers, which other domain could help to solve this problem?

Comment: I would think the domains would be interactive-learning and reinforcement-learning (with theory based on bandit-theory) where one could model the idea of optimizing the lookup-order. Maybe black-box learning can also work (approaches tuned for slow evaluation) but i'm not sure about the exact consequences in regards to orders. **But:** each of these is much much harder to model and learn compared to classic mathematical-programming or classic supervised learning (at least for non RL experts).

Comment: You could also look at [column generation](https://www.google.nl/search?q=column+generation&oq=column+generation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1808j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), where variables are added in the problem iteratively as necessary. Although it has not been developed to tackle expensive parameter lookups, it may be useful.

Comment: LP solvers need a copy of the coefficients `sat(i,j)` so you need to access them only once. If that single access is expensive I would say walk away from this problem.